# Implicit function theorem, sum of derivatives

Tags: implicit-differentiation, chain-rule

Because of the implicit function theorem, is it in general true that:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =   \frac{\partial f}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial b} \frac{\partial b}{\partial x} + \cdots +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial n} \frac{\partial n}{\partial x}$$

Where $f = f(a,b,c, \dots n)$ and $a=a(x),\  b=b(x)\ , \dots ,\  n=n(x)$ ?

Comment: yes. its just a chain rule.

Comment: The chain rule doesn't involve a sum, it just states de derivative of function composition.  f = f(g(x))... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: It does when you look at the chain rule for [functions of several variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

Comment: The notation is unclear. From the last line, it appears that there's a single independent variable $x$. Then what do the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$ etc. refer to? I suspect that the relationship you mean is

$$
\frac{\mathrm d f}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{\mathrm da}{\mathrm dx}+\cdots\;.
$$

Also, how does the implicit function theorem enter into it?